# Issue returning one of two objects when one is NULL using LINQ statement

Tags: .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am struggling to implement what appears to be a relatively straight forward LINQ statement where I wish to return an object from one of two locations depending on whether one exists or not and am receiving the following error on every turn I take.

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Argument types do not match'
```

I have tried many different approaches but always get the same error hence I must not be grasping what I am asking the LINQ processor to do.

I have tried other approaches with structuring my LINQ but the one that most simply highlights my issue is shown below:

```
.Select(
    x => new
    {
        x.Interval,
        x.Enrolment,
        x.Response,
        ResponseOffset = x.Response.ResponseIntervalOffset,
        DefaultOffset = x.Interval.TblChecklistResponseIntervalOffset.FirstOrDefault(
                                     o => o.TimeZoneId == (x.Enrolment.Entity.LocalTimeZoneId ?? defaultTimeZoneId))
    })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.Interval,
        x.Enrolment,
        x.Response,
        Offset = x.ResponseOffset ?? x.DefaultOffset <-- THIS CAUSES ERROR
    })
```

There can sometimes be an Offset linked to the Response but only if the response exists, if the Response does not exist then I wish to use the DefaultOffset.

So although I can return the two Offsets independently I would like a single Offset object that contains one or the other dependent on whether the Response offset exists.

Comment: Are the types of the properties `x.ResponseOffset ?? x.DefaultOffset` the same?

Comment: Yes they are identical object types ```TblChecklistResponseIntervalOffset```

Comment: Something is different, otherwise, there would be no error. What I would do is: Try returning both, and run the query again as if it would throw the error. Debug and see both fields.. that might help you find out the issue..otherwise, we are just guessing as well.

Comment: I added a ```ToList()``` on the end of the first select and everything works fine, I understand I'm now getting two database hits, but it also highlights that the objects are identical, very strange.